# Reformat SAS data set into multiple observations

Tags: formatting, dataset, sas

I am trying to reformat a data set in SAS that I am outputting as a csv. It is currently in the format:

```
Type, Name, data1, data2, data3…
Dog, retriever, 20, 40, 60…
Dog, corgi, 10, 30, 50…
Cat, Persian, 15, 25, 35…
Cat, stray, 1, 2, 3…
```

And I am trying to get it in the format:

```
Dog, retriever, data1, 20
Dog, retriever, data2, 40
Dog, retriever, data3, 60
Dog, Corgi, data1, 10
Dog, corgi, data2, 30
Dog, corgi, data3, 50
Cat, Persian, data1, 15
Cat, Persian, data2, 25
Cat, Persian, data3, 35
Cat, Siamese, data1, 1
Cat, Siamese, data2, 2
Cat, Siamese, data3, 3
```

Do you know the best way to go about this in SAS?

Thanks

Comment: [Read this,then if you have problems, include what you have tried here](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings09/060-2009.pdf) (Lesson 3 is what you need)

Comment: That is just what I needed. Thank you. The 3rd example letter D, I was able to switch the id statement with a by statement and it worked perfectly. The transpose does add an extra column, but I can drop it in the export step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with proc transpose, something like this :

```
PROC TRANSPOSE DATA = ...
    OUT=...
    NAME=ValueSource
    LABEL=ValueDescription
    ;
    BY type name;
    ID <a column with hte same value for all your observations>;
    VAR data1 data2 data3;
RUN;
```

Comment: That is what I was able to use from the paper linked by Scott. I didn't need to use LABEL, ID or VAR for my project. Thank you!